# Equivalence between continuity of $f$ and continuity of the $f_i$ in a countable product of metric spaces.

Tags: continuity, metric-spaces

**Context**

We consider $(E, D)$ a metric space, and $F=\prod_{i=1}^{+\infty} E_i$ a countable product of metric spaces $(E_i, d_i)$.

We know we can choose a product-distance $d$ for $F$.

I choose to define the distances $d'_i$ on $E_i$ by $d'_i (x) = \min \{1, d_i(x)\}$ for $x\in E_i$. And then I defined $d$ by, for $(x_i)_{i\geqslant 1} \in F$ and $(y_i)_{i\geqslant 1} \in F$ : $$ d((x_i), (y_i)) = \sum\limits_{i = 1}^{+\infty} \frac{d'_i (x_i, y_i)}{2^i}$$

Let's consider $f_i$ applications from $E$ to $E_i$, and $f:x\mapsto (f_i (x))_{i\geqslant 1}$ from $E$ to $F$.

**Question**

The queston is : is $f$ continuous in $a \in E$ *if and only if* the $f_i$ are continuous in $a$ ? Is it true for any distance chosen for $F$?

(The result is of course true if the product is finite.)

**My attempt**

- If $f$ is continuous then the $f_i$ are continuous too.

In fact let's take $\varepsilon > 0$. By noting $\varepsilon ' = \varepsilon / 2^i$, we get the existence of $\alpha >0$ such that for all $x\in E$, $D(x,a)\leqslant \alpha \Rightarrow d(f(x), f(a))\leqslant \varepsilon '$. By looking at $d$'s definition, we can see that $d_i(f_i(x), f_i(a))\leqslant 2^i d(f(x), f(a))$. So we have that for all $x\in E$, $D(x,a)\leqslant \alpha \Rightarrow d_i (f_i (x), f_i (a))\leqslant \varepsilon$. So $f_i$ is continuous in $a$.

- If the $f_i$ are continuous, I think there's going to be a problem.

In fact, if, for $\varepsilon > 0$, and for every $i$, we note $\alpha_i >0$ such that for all $x\in E$, $D(x,a)\leqslant \alpha \Rightarrow d_i (f_i (x), f_i (a))\leqslant \varepsilon$, then $\underset{i\geqslant 1}{\inf} \alpha_i$ could be equal to $0$, so that there would be a problem.

But I can't find a counterexample.

Could someone help?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can’t find a counterexample because the result is in fact true.

HINT: Let $\epsilon>0$. There is an $n_0\in\Bbb Z^+$ such that $\sum_{k>n_0}\frac1{2^k}<\frac{\epsilon}2$. Now just choose $\alpha$ small enough so that

$$\sum_{k=1}^{n_0}\frac{d_k'\big(f_k(x),f_k(a)\big)}{2^k}<\frac{\epsilon}2$$

whenever $D(x,a)<\alpha$.

Comment: Ok Thank you. Is the result still true if I choose another distance for $F$?

Comment: @math: Yes, as long as the distance generates the product topology. This is really a property of the product topology, and for topological spaces in general it holds for arbitrary products, not just countable ones.

Comment: Thank you very much. It would be really nice if you could add the proof of the general case to your answer, because I don't really see how to do it. (if it does not take you too much time)

Comment: @math: I’m a little pressed for time, so take a look at the proof of part (ii) of **Theorem** $\mathbf{15.3.7}$ in [this PDF](https://www.hiroleetanaka.com/pdfs/2020-fall-4330-topology-notes-15-product-spaces.pdf). There are a couple of typos: $U\subset X\times Y$ at the bottom of p. $140$ should be $U\subseteq\prod_{\alpha\in\mathcal{A}}X_\alpha$, and $U_{\alpha_n}$ in the second displayed line on p. $141$ should be $V_{\alpha_n}$.